# Algorithm riddle - place numbers in an array by their differences

Tags: arrays, algorithm

ALGORITHM RIDDLE

you get a number x and you have to set the all the from 1 to x twic in an array of size 2x.
the rule is the numbers have to be placed in a cell that is the difference from their value.
for example if you set the number 2 like this:
|**2**| | | | | 
the bex one has to be like this:
|2| |**2**| | |

let's say x=4, then we have an array of 8 cells and we can set the numbers like this:
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
|4|2|3|2|4|3|1|1|

you can place the number in various ways.

can you do the same for the number **10** (array size 20), **12**(array size 24)?
if yes, show how, if not explain why for each number.

Comment: Is it homework? If so - please tag it as such. What *exactly* are you looking for? A general case algorithm? What complexity are you expecting? Last but not least: What did you try?

Comment: I saw that it only works on 1, 4 and 5. It doesn't work on 10 or 12 (and for that matter on 2, 3, 6, 7 and 8 as well).
Each time I try to place a number I start from the top and skips on a cell until the middle.
My theory is that it only works on this numbers: 1, 4 and 5 .

Comment: @MoriaAM: Judging from the pattern I can see in my answer, I think it works for any x equivalent to 0 or 1 mod 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is NP-Complete you must try all possibilities to determine feasibility and to get a result set of possible solutions.

If you want a yes/no answer to whether it can be done that is defined by the function `1/2(4n + (-1)^n - 1)`, plugging values of n starting at 1...infinity will give you the sequence of numbers that are yes answers. Proof not included :)

To clarify, the solution set finding is NP-Complete and the yes/no answer for a given N can be done using the above formula. (I hope I haven't fudged the math on that one, its a generating function)

Comment: `This problem is NP-Complete`: proof/source? Also - if the above formula is correct - the problem is not NP-Complete, because using this function - you can easily evaluate if there is a solution in polynomial time.

Comment: @amit Generating all solutions of the problem is NP-Complete, generating a yes or no on whether for a given N it works is not. It can be shown using combinatorics based on the initial placement of any number. Initial placement in the worst case cannot reduce the problem size significantly in some cases.

Comment: NP-Hardness of problems deals with *Languages*. For example, the TSP is `L={(G,k) | The graph G has a cyclic shortest path with weight k }`. As I see it, in here the language is `L={n | | There is a solution to n} `, which is easily solved according to you. This concept is similar to the [Euler Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) (Given a graph - does it have an eularian path?) - which is NOT NP-Hard

Comment: @amit Giving a yes/no is simple. Giving a solution which is a 2x sized array with the numbers in any correct sequence (the if yes show how part of the question) is NP-Complete.

Comment: What is the language to the NP-Complete problem? Remember that NP-Complete is a class of *languages*, so - what is the language? can you define it formally?

Comment: Reference to this claim: NP-Complete according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete):  `NP-complete (abbreviated NP-C or NPC) is a **class of decision problems**`. Decision problem according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem):  `decision problem is a question in some formal system with a **yes-or-no answer**, depending on the values of some input parameters`

Comment: @amit I've always taken NP-Complete to be that determining an answer is not possible in polynomial time but can be verified in polynomial time so in this case giving an array for a yes answer is non-polynomial but confirming that it is a correct answer can be done with simple checks.

Comment: (1) `NP-Complete to be that determining an answer is not possible in polynomial time`: NP-Complete is defined as "An NP Problem, which has a reduction from every problem in NP to it". We usually proof a problem is NPC by a reduction from a different NPC problem to it (Reduction theorem). The fact is we don't know if it (NPC problem) can be solved polynomially or not ([P=NP Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_%3D_NP_problem)). (2) Unless you can show a reduction from an NPC problem, or at least **show the decision problem** and explain reason for being NPC-you should not claim it to be NPC.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with 10. It is possible with 12. I tried for all integers up to 13, and there is a clear pattern which I'm sure can be proven (but I can't see how at the moment):

```
1  yes
2  no
3  no
4  yes
5  yes
6  no
7  no
8  yes
9  yes
10 no
11 no
12 yes
13 yes
```

It can be solved with a recursive function that tries every possibility, using backtracking if a match cannot be found.